# Linear Independence of a given set

Tags: linear-algebra

The Group ${xcosx,x,cosx}$ is linear independent i cant understand why?
I did managed to prove it was linear dependent by saying that

$xcosx=λcosx$ <=> $λ=x$

How can I prove that this group is linear independent and what is wrong with the proof above?

Thanks :)

Comment: In what way do those functions form an algebraic group?

Comment: Do you mean the group generated by $xcosx$, $x$, and $cosx$? Otherwise $xcosx\cdot x=x^2cosx $ is not in your 'group'.

Comment: I think when you write "group" you just mean "set".

Comment: To show linear independence, you need to show that if
$$
ax+bcosx+cxcosx=0,
$$
then $a=b=c=0$. But you have not told us what the field of scalars is...

Comment: @HenningMakholm correct- fixed the title

Comment: @aaadddaaa: But not the text.

Comment: Consider using \cos x to get $\cos x$ instead of $cos x$. Similarly \sin x. You can also use \iff to get $\iff$

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You're misunderstanding the notation here. You're working in the vector space of all functions $\mathbb R\to\mathbb R$, and have the three functions
$$ \begin{align} f_1(x) &= x\cos x \\
f_2(x) &= x \\
f_3(x) &= \cos x \end{align}$$
and you're then supposed to prove that $\{f_1,f_2,f_3\}$ is a linearly independent set.

This means (since the functions are vectors) that you want to prove that there's no nontrivial linear combination such that
$$\lambda_1 f_1 + \lambda_2 f_2 + \lambda_3 f_3 = 0 $$
where "$=0$" means that the combination *is the zero function*. In yet other words, you need to prove that the only way to achieve
$$ \forall x\in\mathbb R : \lambda_1 x\cos x + \lambda_2 x + \lambda_3\cos x = 0 $$
is to set $\lambda_1=\lambda_2=\lambda_3=0$.

**Hint:** Consider that in particular the last equation must be true for $x=0$ and $x=\frac12\pi$.

Comment: Ok i get that thank :)
But if I set  $\lambda_1=1   \lambda_2=0   \lambda_3=-x$ the equation works and I get  $xcosx=xcosx$ so isn't this set is linear dependent?

Comment: @aaadddaaa: No, the $\lambda_i$s must be _scalars_ -- that is, just real numbers. They can't be functions of $x$.

Comment: Ok i think i got that thanks  a lot :)